How to use a variable in other classes?
I'm using Kivy and Python to make an app, I tried to assign Themevalue depending on what button I click in the class ThemePage and then use it in the class GoPage. Still, the IDE said self.label4 cannot be found, it seems like class GoPage could access the variable in class ThemePage.
Is there any way to link the 2 page and use the same variable??
This is my code
class ThemePage(FloatLayout):
    ThemeValue = 0 
    def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()
      
      print(Themevalue)

      self.label = Image(source='Theme_Button.png', size_hint=(0.3, 0.3), pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.6})
      self.label3 = Image(source='Exp_Bar.png', size_hint=(0.1, 0.1), pos_hint={'center_x': 0.85, 'center_y': 0.9})
      self.label2= Image(source='Bandar_Button.png', size_hint=(0.1, 0.1), pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.8})

      self.button =  Button(text="", background_normal="Back_Button.png", background_down="Back_Button.png", size_hint=(0.1, 0.1), pos_hint={'center_x': 0.05, 'center_y': 0.9})
      self.button2 =  Button(text="", background_normal="Historical_Button.png", background_down="Bander_Button.png", size_hint=(0.21, 0.2), pos_hint={'center_x': 0.3, 'center_y': 0.4})
      self.button3 =  Button(text="", background_normal="Natural_Button.png", background_down="Kiulap_Button.png", size_hint=(0.21, 0.2), pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.4})
      self.button4 =  Button(text="", background_normal="Eat_Button.png", background_down="Bander_Button.png", size_hint=(0.21, 0.2), pos_hint={'center_x': 0.7, 'center_y': 0.4})
      self.label5 = Label(text='0', font_size='30sp', pos_hint={'center_x': 0.92, 'center_y': 0.9})

      self.button.bind(on_press=self.switchback)
      self.button2.bind(on_press=self.goH)
      self.button3.bind(on_press=self.goN)
      self.button4.bind(on_press=self.goE)

      self.add_widget(self.label3)
      self.add_widget(self.label)      
      self.add_widget(self.label2)
      self.add_widget(self.button)
      self.add_widget(self.button2)
      self.add_widget(self.button3)
      self.add_widget(self.button4)
      self.add_widget(self.label5)


    def switchback(self,item):
      myapp.screen_manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction='right')
      myapp.screen_manager.current = 'Des'
    def goH(self, item):
      myapp.screen_manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction='left')
      myapp.screen_manager.current = 'Go'
      global Themevalue 
      ThemePage.Themevalue = 1
    def goN(self,item):
      myapp.screen_manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction='left')
      myapp.screen_manager.current = 'Go'
      global Themevalue
      ThemePage.Themevalue = 2
    def goE(self,item):
      myapp.screen_manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction='left')
      myapp.screen_manager.current = 'Go'
      global Themevalue
      ThemePage.Themevalue = 3
    print(Themevalue)

class GoPage(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()
      self.label1 = Image(source='des_set.jpg', size_hint=(0.3, 0.3), pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.6})
      self.label3 = Image(source='Exp_Bar.png', size_hint=(0.1, 0.1), pos_hint={'center_x': 0.85, 'center_y': 0.9})
      self.label5 = Label(text='0', font_size='30sp', pos_hint={'center_x': 0.92, 'center_y': 0.9})

      self.button =  Button(text="", background_normal="Back_Button.png", background_down="Back_Button.png", size_hint=(0.1, 0.1), pos_hint={'center_x': 0.05, 'center_y': 0.9})
      self.button2 =  Button(text="", background_normal="Arrived.png", background_down="Arrived.png", size_hint=(0.21, 0.2), pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.37})
      self.button3 =  Button(text="active me", size_hint=(0.2, 0.2), pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.9})
      
      self.label6 = Label(text='Themevalue' , font_size='30sp', pos_hint={'center_x': 0.9, 'center_y': 0.7})
      self.add_widget(self.label6)

      if  DestinationPage.Desvalue == 1 and ThemePage.Themevalue == 1: 
       self.label4 = random.choice(bdH_random)

      elif DestinationPage.Desvalue == 1 and ThemePage.Themevalue == 2: 
       self.label4 = random.choice(bdN_random)
      
      elif DestinationPage.Desvalue == 1 and ThemePage.Themevalue == 3: 
       self.label4 = random.choice(bdR_random)

      else: 
        pass
      
      self.button.bind(on_press=self.switchback)
      self.button2.bind(on_press=self.done)
      self.button3.bind(on_press=self.active)

      self.add_widget(self.label3)
      self.add_widget(self.label1)
      self.add_widget(self.label5)
      self.add_widget(self.button)
      self.add_widget(self.button2)
      self.add_widget(self.button3)

    def active(self,item):
      
      self.add_widget(self.label4)


Please reduce your code to a [mre] by removing all code no involved in the error. If you get an error, you need to include the complete error traceback.

As far as I understand, you work with class instances , and I'd prefer to put such variables in global scope, something like this
Themevalue = 0
class ThemePage(FloatLayout):

And then I would refer just by the name of the variable, note that this works correctly if you have created 1 instance of, but as for the fact that it gives an error of an undefined attribute, probably you had the else block worked there, apparently no condition was met, it may even be a problem with the DestinationPage.Desvalue variable, but the code with it is not given, so I can't say anything, I hope the translator translated everything correctly, if anything write

thank you so much, I already fixed the problem.
